# RegEx to modify texts in between tags as3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, replace, html

I have some html tags which will occur in my XML, i would like to replace all texts in between the following format of tags

```
<p><b>Text to be replaced</b><br/></p>
```

Here ***Text to be replaced*** should be replaced with any text.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this :-

```
var pattern:RegExp = /<p><b>.*?<\/b><br\/><\/p>/; 
str.replace(pattern, "<p><b>any text</b><br/></p>");
```

Comment: it is not working, actually what i need is, the text can be anything inside the tags should be replaced.